# find and move files in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to `C++` and I've just read `<C++ Primer> 4ed`. Now I want to implement a little program to help me manage some `mp3` files in my computer.

I have a `.txt` file which includes all the names(part of the names actually) of the files which I want to move(not copy) to a new folder(in the same column). For example, "word" and "file" in the `.txt` and I want to move all the `.mp3` files whose filename contain "word" or "file" to a new folder. Hope my discription is clear, Opps..

I know how to read the strings in `.txt` into a `set<string>` and traverse it, but I have no idea how to search and move a file in a folder. I just want to know what else should I learn so that I can implement this function. I read `C++ Primer` and still I can't do much thing, that's really sad...

Comment: C++ isn't really suited for this task. Mainly, because there is no standard way, so you'd need a library or write everything yourself. It's certainly possible, but you're probably better off with a scripting solution.

Comment: Well the standard c++ library was not developed in such tasks in mind.  There is nothing there to support os filesystem operations. However, I would probably give [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename) a shot if I were determined to stick with c++. But for such things I like python better.

Comment: I'd go with Boost.Filesystem too, at least until wide C++14 support appears.

Answer (score 27):

To move a file in C++, you do not have to use external libraries like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), but you can use standard functionality.

There is the new [filesystem API](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), which has a [rename](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
  try {
    std::filesystem::rename("from.txt", "to.txt");
  } catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The drawback is to compile it, you need a recent C++17 compiler. (I tested it on gcc 8.0.1, and I also needed to link against `-lstdc++fs`).

But what should work on any C++ compiler today, is the old C API, which also provides [rename (cstdio)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

int main() {
  if(std::rename("from.txt", "to.txt") < 0) {
    std::cout << strerror(errno) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But note that in both cases, the rename will fail if the source and destination files are not on the same filesystem. Then you will see an error like this:

```
filesystem error: cannot rename: Invalid cross-device link [from.txt] [/tmp/to.txt]
```

In that case, you can only make a copy and then remove the original file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("from.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  std::ofstream out("to.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  out << in.rdbuf();
  std::remove("from.txt");
}
```

Or with the new API:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
  try {
    std::filesystem::copy("from.txt", "to.txt");
    std::filesystem::remove("from.txt");
  } catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the rename will fail if the source and destination files are not on the same filesystem" - this is not true.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev If you check the documentation of the "rename" system call, you see that rename across different file system results in a EXDEV error. At least on POSIX systems, you cannot assume that rename will work in that case. Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html

Answer (score 2):

Use **rename()** function to move a file

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char oldname[] = "C:\\Users\\file_old.txt";
 char newname[] = "C:\\Users\\New Folder\\file_new.txt";
 
 /* Deletes the file if exists */
 if (rename(oldname, newname) != 0)
  perror("Error moving file");
 else
  cout << "File moved successfully";
 
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way for this to work only using std would be to read the file completely using a `std::ifstream` and then write it to the new location with a `std::ofstream`. This will however not remove the old file from disk. So basically you create a copy of the file. Its also much slower than a real move.

The optimal solution is to use OS specific APIs like win32 which e.g provide a [MoveFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Poco provides an platform independent abstraction of such APIs. See: http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.File.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way to move a file in Windows is using the [MoveFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile) function as it is shown in the following code.

```
std::wstring oldPath = L"C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\example\\text.txt";
std::wstring newPath = L"C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\example1\\text.txt";

bool result = MoveFile(newPath.c_str(), oldPath.c_str());

if (result)
    printf("File was moved!");
else
    printf("File wasn't moved!");
```

Answer (score -1):

under Windows run `system` call with batch commands:

```
system("move *text*.mp3 new_folder/");
system("move *word*.mp3 new_folder/");
```

Under Unix same with shell syntax.