# How to move file in Linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux

How do you move a file from one location to another using a C++ program in Linux?
I've written a program to do this and it runs, but when I try to move a file to a different directory it doesn't move the file, I get the error message from the cout statement. When I try to just rename the file, moving it to the same directory with a new name it works. How can I fix my code so it will be able to move files to another directory?

Here's the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int result=1;
  char oldname[500];
  char newname[500];
  cout << "Enter the name of a file you want to move (include directory structure)";
  cin >> oldname;
  cout << "Enter the new location (include directory structure)";
  cin >> newname;

  result = rename( oldname , newname );
  if ( result == 0 )
    cout << "File successfully moved" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Error moving file" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
I added perror to my code and the error message displayed is "Error moving file: No such file or directory" even though the directory I tried moving it to does exist and it has create and delete files permissions.

Comment: Wahtever you are trying to do, first try it on terminal with `rename` command. Once you are able to succeed with it then you can try doing the same thing with a program

Comment: Look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201663/find-and-move-files-in-c

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161243/how-to-move-file-from-one-folder-to-different-folder-in-linux) answer might give you a little more insight.

Comment: I can't believe someone needs to ask this: what exactly do you type in for `oldname`?  What does `ls -l` say for that string?  Same for `newname`.

Comment: the `rename` function does **not** create directories. So, you'd better create them yourself before moving.

Comment: @Serge I wasn't trying to use rename to create any directories - just to move the file from one directory to another one. Both directories exist before I run the program.

Comment: your message either tells you that your source file does not exist or that your output directory does not exist. could probably be a permission issue. is your output directory writable by you? is your source file readable?

Comment: @MichaelBurr You were rude. This is my first time using Linux and this a place for people of all skill levels to ask questions. Your suggestion to check ls -l was helpful and I found the original file I was trying to move wasn't listed so I moved a file listed and it worked.

Comment: @Serge I found that the source file didn't exist, though checking [ ! -f  directory/filename ] showed that it did exist. I guess I did something wrong there but it worked with a different file.

Comment: [How to move file from one folder to different folder in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20161243/608639), [Moving a file on Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17438493/608639), [Faster way to move file in c++ on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19565085/608639), [Moving files from one directory into another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42535318/608639), [How can I copy a file from one directory to another in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7267295/608639), etc...

Comment: @softengstu: I apologize if my comment was excessively rude.  I had no idea this was your first encounter with Linux, but I'm not sure knowing that would have changed my comment much. I think it's reasonable to expect that a question about why an API fails to work should contain such basic information as the error returned and/or the specifics about the inputs to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix your program depends on the reason why the move (rename) failed.

The reason for the failure can be found using [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

---

In this case, it was necessary to make sure that the source file exists.

For all things that need to be considered to robustly implement moving, I recommend studying an implementation of `mv` command.

Comment: The error I got with perror is "No such file or directory". The directory I tried moving it to does exist and I set permissions to 'create and delete files' so I don't see why I'd get that error message.

Comment: @softengstu How did you verify that the directory exists?

Comment: I tried moving it to the Documents folder which I see in Home, but when I ran a shell script just now to double check it seems like it doesn't exist. I also created a directory and then tried moving the file to the directory I just created and I get the same error message.

Comment: If it seems like it doesn't exist, then that's clearly the reason why you cannot move a file there.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the shell script (didn't include the full directory structure initially) - it does exist.

Comment: Did you include the full directory structure in your program?

Comment: Yes, I used the same full directory structure in my program as I used in the shell script that showed the file exists - for both the original and destination directories.

Comment: By "full directory structure", do you mean absolute path? Or did you use a relative path?

Comment: Yes, I used the absolute path

Comment: I checked ls -l and the original file I was trying to move wasn't listed for some reason. I tested the program with a different file and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work in most cases. But you are ignoring some important things in which case it will break :

- The obvious things like permissions, non-existing path, ...
- Paths of 500 chars or more. Don't use static allocated memory for `oldname` and `newname`
- Moving between filesystems is not possible with `rename()` so do it like this ( and include `iostream` )

  ```
  ifstream ifs(oldname, ios::in | ios::binary);
  ofstream ofs(newname, ios::out | ios::binary);
  ofs << ifs.rdbuf();
  remove(oldname);
  ```

  Before the `remove()` your total disk space will be a bit less.

  - This doesn't matter if your are moving between filesystems because only the free space on the filesystem with `newname` will shrink and this is free space you have because otherwise you wouldn't able to move the file here
  - If `oldname` and `newname` are on the same filesystem and you really care about this temporary loss then check whether you'll be using the same filesystem and use `rename()` after all.

Comment: Your suggested copy to other fs fails to preserve permissions that move should preserve.

Comment: Good point ! atime, mtime, ctime, UID and GID are also not preserved. This can all be avoided (if needed) by using `fstat()` on the original file before reading the contents. And before writing one could use `mknod` using the metadata from memory and only start writing after the file is created. Your code will become really long though...

Comment: The in and out flags are redundant btw.

Comment: Rather than always copying then deleting, it would be better to attempt to call `rename()` first, then do a copy-then-delete if that fails. Renaming across filesystems and failing over to copying is faster and simpler than tracking down the mountpoint and comparing manually. Portability bonus: on Windows, `rename()` calls `MoveFile()` which CAN move across volumes, so this "does the right thing" in all cases.